# Upgrade the Graphics Card for a Dell Dimension 3100

Tags: windows-xp, hardware-rec, graphics-card

I have a Dell Dimension 3100 Desktop with a 128MB Graphics Card Integrated into the Mother Board. I need to upgrade this 128MB to at least 256MB or 512MB if the system will support same. I am told by Dell that all I have is a PCIx1 slot and that they do not stock a Graphics Card for this. I was told to shop around at Amazon and ebay etc and I would find one there. I have shopped around for some time now and do not know exactly what I am looking for. There are several PCI Graphics Card out there but which one would be the correct one for a Dell Dimension 3100. Can you help me resolve this problem. If you know of a PCIx1 card that will sort out my problem you might please let me have all the details for to purchase it.

Regards,

Pat,

Comment: What are you hoping to accomplish with this upgrade?  Is there an issue with the graphics, or are you hoping to play a new game?  Just want to make sure that you're not still going to be hitting a different bottleneck.

Comment: Please *don't* use signatures or taglines in your posts. - http://superuser.com/faq

Answer (score 1):

I'd second the recommendation to go to a local computer/electronics store and ask for help there. In the first instance they'll be more likely to sell you something that will work in your hardware, instead of you trying to figure out the options from a web site or take pot luck on eBay. In the second instance if it does go wrong it'll be far easier for you to take it back and organise a replacement/refund.

Any extra you might pay for the card will be more than covered by the money you won't spend on  delivery charges and the time you'll save.

Answer (score 0):

Any PCI Express x1 video card will work on your system. I would go to www.newegg.com (no affiliation), they have great prices and search tools to help you find what you need.
Keep in mind you MAY have to disable the on board video card in the system BIOS after you install the new card.

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure that you have adequate power to support the new video card.

Answer (score 0):

One other option to consider if you're trying to find an older card is to see if you have a pawn shop or something similar that specializes in electronics.  When the video card in my older Dell died, I was able to replace it for $12.

I find that the people in these places who are responsible for evaluating trade-ins are usually pretty knowledgeable, and can probably help you figure out what you need if you're not sure yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Hiya I have a Dell Dimension 3100 running The Sims 2. The best graphics card for this computer is an nVidia Ge Force 6200. The Dimension 3100 hasn't got a PCIe X16 Slot but however has a PCIe X1 Slot. Any PCI or PCIe X1 Full Height Bracket cards will fit.  Hope this helps, Roan.

Comment: You may be able to find one on eBay from £5-£30. Roan.